# When will ApiController be disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp MVC application. I create an API controller there.  In the controller, I set up a connection to SharePoint then fetch the data and return it.

but I have a question. Generally in a console app, we will dispose the connection (C# using block) after all operations get finished.

now a bro tells me that we do not need to do it as the connection is in a controller. when the request goes to end, the controller will be disposed, the connection won't affect the performance or waste resources.

if I do not dispose the connection, will it be reused in the next request? or it will response more quickly?

Thanks

Comment: Your "bro" is incorrect (for connections stored in Controller fields) _unless_ your `Controller` implements `IDisposable` **and** explicitly closes/disposes of the connection in the `protected virtual void Dispose` method - **or** if the connection was created (and is _owned_) by your DI container.

Comment: I assume you're referring to `SqlConnection` , in which case `SqlConnection` has its own internal connection-pool that it manages for you, you shouldn't normally need to do anything beyond the correct (and timely!) disposal of `SqlConnection` objects (though I am unsure if a `SqlConnection` object takes an exclusive-lease on internal pooled connections until it's disposed... or not). While the .NET GC will finalize (and dispose) of your connection objects _eventually_ this is a non-deterministic, potentially time-unbounded situation that you **must not** depend-on.